# LitElement: drag and drop absolute positioned items inside a defined container

Tags: typescript, drag-and-drop, lit-element

I'm trying to create an application, where items on a specific container (with background image) can be dragged around. The items are positioned `absolute`, the outer container is positioned `relative`.

Code looks like this:

```
static get styles(): CSSResult {
    return css`
      :host {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
      }

      #itemWrapper {
        width: 800px;
        height: 400px;

        position: relative;
        background-image: url(../static/images/background.png);
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
      }

      my-custom-item {
        position: absolute;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
    `;
  }

  protected render(): TemplateResult {
    return html`
        <div id='itemWrapper'>
            <my-custom-item id='item1' style='top:50px; left:100px;'></my-custom-item>
            <my-custom-item id='item2' style='top:150px; left:100px;'></my-custom-item>
            <my-custom-item id='item3' style='top:250px; left:100px;'></my-custom-item>
        </div>
    `;
  }
```

I've added some event handlers to `my-custom-item` (hint: the items are generated through an array so I can access the `id`):

```
<my-custom-item
    id='${item.id}'
    style='top:50px; left:100px;'
    draggable=true
    @dragstart="${(e: Event) => this._dragEvent('dragstart', e, item.id)}"
    @dragenter="${(e: Event) => this._dragEvent('dragenter', e, item.id)}"
    @dragover="${(e: Event) => this._dragEvent('dragover', e, item.id)}"
    @dragend="${(e: Event) => this._dragEvent('dragend', e, item.id)}"
    @dragleave="${(e: Event) => this._dragEvent('dragleave', e, item.id)}"
    @drop="${(e: Event) => this._dragEvent('drop', e, item.id)}">
</my-custom-item>
```

And the `_dragEvent()` method looks like this ([as found on GitHub](https://github.com/open-wc/lit-demos/issues/4#issuecomment-501636146)):

```
protected _dragEvent(eventType: string, evt: Event, itemId: string | number | undefined) {
    console.log('eventType', eventType);
    console.log('evt', evt);
    console.log('itemId', itemId);

    switch (eventType) {
      case 'dragstart':
        this._activeDragItem = this.shadowRoot?.querySelector(`#${itemId}`);
        break;
      case 'dragenter':
        if (this._activeDragItem == null) return;
        this._moveItem(this._activeDragItem, itemId);
        evt.preventDefault();
        break;
      case 'dragover':
        evt.preventDefault();
        break;
      case 'dragleave':
        if (this._activeDragItem == null) return;
        break;
      case 'drop':
        if (this._activeDragItem == null) return;
        this._moveItem(this._activeDragItem, itemId);
        break;
      case 'dragend':
        if (this._activeDragItem == null) return;
        this._activeDragItem = null;
        break;

    }
}

protected _moveItem(item: any, itemId: string | number | undefined) {
    console.log('moving', item);
}
```

But the items can't be moved and I don't get why it doesn't work. `drop` is never fired...
Can anyone give a hint or working example of dragging items? Not only "sorting a list".

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Usually the events *over* and *drop* are set to the **target** of the drag and drop. (Not the object being drga)  In your case, I would expect them to be set on itemWrapper.

Comment: Thanks, @vals, that's the hint... facepalming myself...

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add `draggable="true"` to your element.

Also, you can check this documentation:
[HTML Drag and drog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) or [Dragged element with a absolute position](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_draggable.asp)

Comment: As you can see, `draggable='true'` is already set to `<my-custom-item>`

Answer (score 0):

I think that what Raymon wanted to say is that draggable is set in your code `draggable=true`, but it should be `draggable="true"` with quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Look into this sample draggable web-component project which was built using LitElement with JavaScript. I hope it will help you in this problem.

https://github.com/rayanaradha/Draggable-web-component

This project contains 3 classes.

DragTestOnElement - Component for Draggable item.

DragContainer  - Component for Item Container.

DragArea - UI

In this project Draggable Items can be dragged and dropped between Item Containers.

Comment: beware this may not work correctly on mobile devices